# How to set log Rotation in Quarkus on time basis?

Tags: maven, logging, quarkus

I am building an application using Quarkus and i am using logging.
How could i set log rotation on daily basis or any given time basis?

I didn't get anything related this on https://quarkus.io/guides/logging.

Answer (score 0):

If you set `quarkus.log.file.rotation.file-suffix` the file will automatically be rotated based on the suffix you select (see [this](https://quarkus.io/guides/logging#quarkus-log-logging-log-config_quarkus.log.file.rotation.file-suffix) for more information).
However, the file will **also** be rotated when `quarkus.log.file.rotation.max-file-size` is reached (it defaults to `10MB` if not set). So if you never want this to happen, you will have to set `quarkus.log.file.rotation.max-file-size` to some very large value.

Answer (score 0):

In application.properties file add max-file-size to a large number and and set suffix with : **.yyy-MM-dd**

```
quarkus.log.console.json=true

quarkus.log.file.enable=true
quarkus.log.file.level=INFO
quarkus.log.file.path=my-app.log
quarkus.log.file.rotation.max-backup-index=30
quarkus.log.file.rotation.file-suffix=.yyyy-MM-dd
quarkus.log.file.rotation.max-file-size=1000M
```